# How to test if there's a Next.js production build with custom node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, next.js

I am able to run a custom node.js server with next.js like this:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

To start the development environment, I can run `node server.js`,
To create a production build I can run `npm run build`,
and finally to run the production build (`npm start`), I can use `NODE_ENV=production node server.js`

I'm having an issue when I try to run my app in production mode *without* a production build, it doesn't throw an error like normally when you do it from the next.js cli without a custom server.

The only thing that gets logged when I run production mode without a build is
`info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin`

No error, no logs.

---

How would I be able to detect if a production build exists or not?